# Smart pointer to atl com interface

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, atl

I have an atl-com dll that has an interface IMyInterface. I created a client with #import "Project.tlb" and it was generated the correct Project.tlh and Project.tli. So I included Project.tlb in my client. Now I'm trying to call the IMyInterfacePtr that #import generated like this:

```
IMyInterfacePtr *i;
CLSID clsid = __uuidof(Test);
REFIID iid = __uuidof(IMyInterfacePtr);
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, iid, (void**) &i);
```

So using the pointer to interface:

```
i->MyMethod();
```

But it didn't recognize "MyMethod", it's only showing the IDispatch interface that is from which my IMyInterface inherits.

What Am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: That should be `IMyInterfacePtr i;` - lose the asterisk, and that iid should be `__uuiof(IMyInterface)`. This assuming you used the `comutil` smart pointer macros when defining `IMyInterfacePtr` (and you are if you're importing from a tlb as you specified).

Comment: Thanks @WhozCraig! Works like a charm!